# Invoke the Lambda Function from Serverless Canary Deployments Plugin

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, canary-deployment

I use the [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/) to develop an application using AWS Lambda using Node. I would like to use [serverless-plugin-canary-deployments](https://github.com/davidgf/serverless-plugin-canary-deployments) to run a pre-traffic test of a Lambda Function.

How do I invoke the new Lambda Function from the pre-traffic hook?

I do not want to simply call the Lambda Function's handler from within the pre-traffic hook;

I would like the test to demonstrate that the permissions on the Lambda Function function are sufficient. Therefore I would like to actually invoke the Lambda Function, rather than simply calling its handler from within the pre-traffic hook.